# Change settings of autotools C project in Eclipse

Tags: c, eclipse, autotools

I would like to change something in code of an open source program. This is using autotools, so I opened it in eclipse as autotools project. I built project successful, but I don't know how to easy add some code, which using mysql.h and my_global.h. Specifically, where have I add:

```
/usr/include/mysql
-lmysqlclient
-L/usr/lib
```

In autotools project I can't find something similar like Project properties-> C/C++ Build-> Settings -> Tools settings(C compiler, C linker).

If it doesn't possible without an autotools skills, I screw that. Thanks for answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Things like `-L/p/a/t/h` are flags that the user will add when running configure, but `/usr/lib` is not normally added since is is searched by the linker by default.  If you are modifying the source code by adding a new dependency on `libmysqlclient`, you very likely just need to look in `configure.ac` (or `configure.in`, but if `configure.in` exists please consider filing a bug to change the name or change it yourself) and add the line:

```
AC_CHECK_LIB([mysqlclient],[my_init])
```

It is very likely that there are already invocations of `AC_CHECK_LIB` in `configure.ac`, and you should add this line at the end of the appropriate section.  This will cause the generated configure script to check the usability of the library at configure time and add the appropriate -l flags at link time.  As always, the user is responsible for setting `CPPFLAGS` and `LDFLAGS` appropriately to populate `-D` and `-L` flags.

It is likely that `mysql` provides a `*.pc` file and you may see examples using `PKG_CHECK_MODULES`.  Doing so will involve more work on your part, and is (in my opinion) less correct.